# How to find the correct operation to fit a limited set of operations?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find a math operation indicated by -> which will result in y given x.

```
x -> y
0 -> 0
1 -> 6
2 -> 5
3 -> 4
4 -> 3
5 -> 2
6 -> 1
```

Of course, 7 - x works for all of these except for

```
0 -> 0
```

Is there a simple operation that would fit all of these examples? How could I find that operation? Are there better ways to describe this problem?

Comment: Your question is vague. In particular it's unclear what you mean by "operation." If you are looking for a polynomial function which passes through all those points, look up Lagrange interpolation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the remainder after dividing it by $7$, that is  $$ 7 - x \mod 7$$

Comment: Simple, thanks!